# c# Sharp I get an error in use Thread (Keyword this is Not valid)

Tags: c#

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqsLQ.png]

The keyword `this` is not valid

Can you help me?

```
static void ThreadFuncEven()
{
  Thread.Sleep(20000);
  HtmlElementCollection elc2 = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
  int count = 0;
  foreach (HtmlElement el in elc2)
  {
    if (el.GetAttribute("data-gtm").Equals("like-toggle"))
    {
      el.InvokeMember("Click");
      if (++count >= 50)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the `this` keyword inside a `static` method. Either make the method an `instance` method or change your code.

Comment: I do not know how to do it :/

Comment: If in the `class` where you are doing `HtmlElementCollection elc2 = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");` exists a `webBrowser` field then just transform your method signature like `<access modifier> void ThreadFuncEven()`. Otherwise you would need to create the `WebBrowser` instance by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help  As you say l did System.InvalidCastException "    HtmlElementCollection elc2 = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");   " 
It gives such an error :(